# First WordPress template

Tags: php, html5, template, wordpress

I wrote my first template, but didn't include any styling. What do you think? What's good what's bad?

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: Email product info
*/


//checks required fields
$allFormPosts = array("address", "email", "xsize", "ysize", "zsize");
foreach($allFormPosts as $formPost){
    if(isset($_POST[$formPost])){
        ${$formPost} = trim($_POST[$formPost]);
    }else{
        $formNotValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!isset($formNotValid)){
    //checks address
    if(!strlen($address)){
        $hasError = true;
        $addressError = "You forgot to enter address.";
    }
    //checks email
    if(!strlen($email)){
        $hasError = true;
        $emailError = "You didn't enter email address";
    }
    else if(!is_email($email)){
        $hasError = true;
        $emailError = "Email address is not valid.";
    }
    //check x
    if(!strlen($xsize)){
        $hasError = true;
        $xsizeError = "You forgot to enter \"x\" size.";
    }
    else if(!is_numeric($xsize) || $xsize <= 0){
        $hasError = true;
        $xsizeError = "\"$xsize\" is not valid.";
    }
    //checks y
    if(!strlen($ysize)){
        $hasError = true;
        $ysizeError = "You forgot to enter \"y\" size.";
    }
    else if(!is_numeric($ysize) || $ysize <= 0){
        $hasError = true;
        $ysizeError = "\"$ysize\" is not valid.";
    }
    //checks z
    if(!strlen($zsize)){
        $hasError = true;
        $zsizeError = "You forgot to enter \"z\" size.";
    }
    else if(!is_numeric($zsize) || $zsize <= 0){
        $hasError = true;
        $zsizeError = "\"$zsize\" is not valid.";
    }
    //sends email if form is valid
    if(!isset($hasError)){
        $subject = "Package";
        $body = "Package is being sent to $address. Package size is $xsize-$ysize-$zsize cm";
        mail($email, $subject, $body);
    }
}
?>


<?php get_header(); ?>

<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="productForm" method="post">

<?php
if(isset($hasError) || isset($formNotValid))
    echo "<p>There has been an error.</p>";
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Address*:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php if(isset($address) && !isset($addressError)) echo $address;?>" required="required" placeholder="Enter place">
                <?php if(isset($addressError)){
                    echo $addressError;
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email*:</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($email) && !isset($emailError)) echo $email;?>" required="required" placeholder="Enter email">
                <?php if(isset($emailError)){
                    echo $emailError;
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Size*:</td>
            <td><input type="number" size="3" placeholder="x" name="xsize" required="required" min="1" value="<?php if(isset($xsize) && !isset($xsizeError)) echo $xsize;?>">
                <input type="number" size="3" placeholder="y" name="ysize" required="required" min="1" value="<?php if(isset($ysize) && !isset($ysizeError)) echo $ysize;?>">
                <input type="number" size="3" placeholder="z" name="zsize" required="required" min="1" value="<?php if(isset($zsize) && !isset($zsizeError)) echo $zsize;?>">cm
                <?php if(isset($xsizeError)){
                    echo $xsizeError;
                }
                if(isset($ysizeError)){
                    echo $ysizeError;
                }
                if(isset($zsizeError)){
                    echo $zsizeError;
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
    <button type="submit" value="submitted">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite fine. Something I don't like though is the mild overuse / abuse of `isset` and `strlen`.
Take this code for example:

> ```
> $allFormPosts = array("address", "email", "xsize", "ysize", "zsize");
> foreach($allFormPosts as $formPost){
>     if(isset($_POST[$formPost])){
>         ${$formPost} = trim($_POST[$formPost]);
>     }else{
>         $formNotValid = true;
>         break;
>     }
> }
>
> if(!isset($formNotValid)){
> ```

The main purpose of `isset` is to check if something was set at all,
and is best used to check things not within your control.
`isset($_POST[$formPost])` is an appropriate use case:
indeed, you have no control over what was sent to your script,
whether from a proper user input form, or possibly from a `curl` script.

On the other hand, you do have control over `$formNotValid`;
it's your own variable you defined yourself, and you should use it better.
This variable should be a boolean: it should be either true or false,
there is no point in permitting "not set".

It would be better to initialize this variable yourself,
and eliminate the possibility of it not being set.
Initialize it to `false`,
check your form with the loop as before,
updating `$formNotValid` as needed,
and then do a boolean check instead of an `isset`:

```
$formNotValid = false;
foreach($allFormPosts as $formPost){
    // ...
}

if(!$formNotValid){
```

You cannot know what scripts get included before your script is called.
Some other script could possibly set a value to `$formNotValid`,
breaking your script.
By initializing it explicitly to a meaningful value yourself,
you eliminate an ambiguity, and with it a bug waiting to happen.

I recommend the same treatment for `$hasError` as well.
Initialize it first to `false`, and check it with `if ($hasError) { ... }` instead of resorting to `isset`.

---

Although it's true that `strlen` should always return 0 or higher,
it would be more natural to write conditions on `strlen` like this:

```
// this is kind of "clever"
//if(!strlen($address)){

// this is more natural
if (strlen($address) == 0) {
```

This may be a matter of taste though.

---

Borrowing from the standard in other languages,
I recommend using more spaces in loops and conditionals, like this, notice the difference from the original:

```
foreach ($allFormPosts as $formPost) {
    if (isset($_POST[$formPost])) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If I dont know with variable names have been used before(other files, libraries) shoudnt I check all of them with isset();?

Comment: Variables you define yourself should always be set to something. Use `isset` only for variables you didn't create yourself, variables you're receiving from somewhere else, typically the fields of `$_POST[...]` or `$_GET[...]`. Variables you control, you should have meaningful values always.

Answer (score 1):

**XSS**

[XSS via Post](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060814/exploiting-cross-site-scripting-through-post/) is possible, so you shouldn't just echo `$address` in the form, and you should also not put the invalid input unsanitized in the error message (`$xsize`, etc).

**Validation**

You check `strlen` on every input field. You can remove all those checks and just move the `strlen` checks to your `foreach` loop (you can still set the error messages there).

**Misc**

- comments: your `checks [something]` comments are not really needed, it's obvious from the code what is happening.
- I'm not an HTML expert, but as far as I can tell, using a table to format a form is a bit outdated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699358/styling-a-table-or-a-list-based-form-so-that-the-labels-and-input-fields-width-a) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3888746/HTML-Forms-From-Basics-to-Style-Layouts.htm) for example). A better approach would be to use `label`.
- you have `formNotValid` and `hasError`, but the names don't really tell a reader what the difference between them is. I would just get rid of `hasError` and use `formNotValid` in all cases.